# Check input data by MySQL schema or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation, schema

Suppose I'd like to check whether a comment is duplicated or not.

I have two options:

1) Create a query to database and check for it: 
    select * from comments where content=$santized_content and post_id=$id

2) Create a unique index for comment and post_id and catch MySQL error.

It's important for my complex and busy app to decrease number of queries to database as much as possible. However the first option is more usual and  readable.

You can generalize this question to other situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is definitely faster than PHP. I would always prefer using a failing INSERT or a REPLACE against a suitable key than checking in PHP.

The only exception would probably be that your key becomes very complex which will obviously create overhead on MySQL for all queries run against that table. However, there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer to the question what would be too complex to be worthwhile doing. It's largely a matter of real life testing.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer number 2 ,

1. your PHP script will less code.
2. It will check automatically whenever comment is duplicate or not.

then this is the function of UNIQUE.